# get and set values using threadlocal or cookies in wcf service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, cookies, httphandler

i have a wcf service deployed in iis and running. then i have created the http handlers as ny extending IHttpHandler class and in web.config file added entry as below

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
         <add verb="*" path="*.sync" type="MyHandler.SyncHandler, MyHandler" />
      </httpHandlers>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

and in the **begin method** of handler i have **set the value in both threadlocal and cookie** as

```
ThreadName.Value = "sample";
```

and

```
httpCookie userCookie = new HttpCookie("Cookiename");
                userCookie.Value = "sample";                
                context.Response.Cookies.Add(userCookie);
```

and while retrieving those values **inside wcf service** application **i am getting null values** from both cookies and thread local.

the code which i used was

```
 return (String)ThreadName.Value;
```

i do not know where i went wrong or the approach which i used is correct!

waiting for your valuable suggestions and comments

Comment: how do you call your WCF service?

Comment: @vibhu normally in system.service model tag with configuring endpoint in it from client application

Comment: Pardon me if I could not make myself clear, I am trying to understand how you make call to the service, or in general a little bit about flow? So you created a httpHandler and in that you make call to your service hosted in IIS or how is it done?

Comment: @vibhu thanks for your interest .. though i will call the hosted service from a client application purpose of that handler is just to catch the name from incoming service url as

Comment: @vibhu http://localhost/ss/service.svc?t=sample what that handler will do is to retrieve the sample name and set in in thread local or cookies there by that service should receive that value either through cookies or thread local

Comment: did you try to check the Thread Id of the thread invoking your handler and of the thread running the service? 
I am little confused on how the url localhost/ss/service.svc?t=sample invoke a handler which you have mentioned in web.config (.sync extension).
Try to see if using applying a custom behavior to the service helps your case - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/22/wcf-extensibility-iservicebehavior.aspx